# Function to get/pass multidimension arrays

Tags: winforms, function, c++-cli

I am doing a small C++ Windows Form project with visual studio 2010. My code is getting too large so I have decided to have some functions in header.h files. My problem is I do not know how to make a function to receive/return multi-dimension arrays. Any help appreciated

Comment: Is it plain c++ or c++/cli ?

Comment: Just return the pointer of the multi dimensional array if it's plain c++ or return Array^ type if it is CLI.

Comment: It is C++/CLI. Can you give me a simple example here. TNX

Answer (score 1):

For managed arrays, you can specify the dimension as the second template parameter to the **array** keyword:

```
void TakesArray(array<Object^, 2>^ a)
{
    ...
}

array<Object^, 2>^ ReturnsArray()
{
}
```

For raw unmanaged arrays, it's a little complicated. Taking an array looks like:

```
void TakesArray(SomeType a[5][10])
{
}
```

But you need to be aware that that's actually equivalent to:

```
void TakesArray(SomeType (*a)[10])
{
}
```

Which means that it really takes *a pointer to an array of 10 elements*. It also means that the size of the second dimension (and higher dimensions, if you add more) is part of the type, but the size of the first dimension is not, which in turn means that you can call it with a 2-dimensional array whose second dimension's size must be 10, and whose first dimension can be of any size.

Returning a raw unmanaged array is even weirder:

```
void (*ReturnsArray())[10]
{
}
```

Anyway, there's rarely a need to use that syntax (that's why it's uncommon). A better way is to use an array class such as std::vector:

```
void TakesArray(const vector<vector<SomeTipe>>& v)
{
}

vector<vector<SomeType>> ReturnsArray()
{
}
```

Technically that's not a multidimensional array but an array of arrays, but you can use it much like a multidimentional array.